# ScrollTop property of HTML DOM element giving integer/double values on different monitors

Tags: javascript, html

While doing some debugging, I was messing around with some html and javascript in the TryIt editor on w3schools. I have a curious problem where the scrollTop property of a html dom element returns integers when viewed on one monitor and double values when viewed on another.

This happens on Chrome 68.0.3440.106 but not on Edge 42.17134.1.0.

Here's my code:
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FV27R380RB8R

Can someone tell me why this happens and if there's a way to force it to return integers please?

Answer (score 0):

zoom value on both browsers might not be 100%

Comment: The zoom does seem to affect it but on Chrome, it has different values on different monitors even when the zoom is 100% on both.